Deviation between results from OpenFDA API and Maude - Adverse events medical devices PRD Code
When running this query via the OpenFDA API: https://api.fda.gov/device/event.json?search=(device.device_report_product_code:KQM+AND+date_report:%5B20230101+TO+20230430%5D)&limit=20
From the result we get 3 hits (reported AE´s on prd code KQM)
When running the exact same search via Maude we get 16 hits?
Why is there a deviation in the results?

I tried running the query you mentioned via MAUDE UI and got back 2 (two) hits instead of 16: 

Still deviation though :( Any idea what the reason might be?
